# True or false: if $(a_{n+1} -a_n)$ is a bounded sequence, $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}(\frac{a_n}{n^2})=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Need help with this question:

> True or false: if $(a_{n+1} -a_n)$ is a bounded sequence, then
>   $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}(\frac{a_n}{n^2})=0$

I couldn't find counterexample and couldn't not prove it.

Comment: True by Cesàro-Stolz or by telescoping, of course. The exponent $2$ can be replaced by any exponent $>1$ and the claim still is true.

Answer (score 4):

Avail yourself of "telescoping."

$$a_n = a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k - a_{k-1}).$$

Comment: $a_0$ is not defined as $n$ is a natural number

Comment: Note that you can use $a_1$ and start the sum with $k=2$.